# mean/sd as a value, not a vector

Tags: r, vector, mean

the mean and sd functions in R return a numerical vector of length 1.
I would like to calculate mean and standard deviation as a single value, not a vector.

This seems simple enough: just take the first element of the vector returned by mean/sd. (diffs[[i]] is a numeric vector)

```
meanvec<-mean(diffs[[i]])
mean<-meanvec[1]
```

However, this results in ANOTHER length-1 vector!!

```
Browse[1]> meanvec
[1] 0.9940868
Browse[1]> mean
[1] 0.9940868
Browse[1]> class(meanvec)
[1] "numeric"
Browse[1]> class(mean)
[1] "numeric"
```

How can I obtain the mean and sd as a simple value, not a length-1 numeric vector?? 
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no such thing as a single value in R. As far a R is concerned, scalars are length 1 vectors and there is nothing you can do about that. However, you can use a length 1 vector as if it were a scalar in R, so I don't see what the problem is?

Note that there are some inefficiencies in R due to the lack of scalars and scalar-specific & -optimised operations. These have been discussed within the context of a new language similar to R but modified to address some of its weaknesses, including the lack of true scalars.

Ross Ihaka discusses the scalar issue in the [text of a paper given as JSM2010](http://www.stat.auckland.ac.nz/~ihaka/downloads/JSM-2010.pdf) (PDF). Some blog commentators at the time also cover Ross' thoughts:

- Christian Robert: ["simply start over and build something better"](http://xianblog.wordpress.com/2010/09/13/simply-start-over-and-build-something-better/)
- Andrew Gelman: ["Ross Ihaka to R: Drop Dead"](http://andrewgelman.com/2010/09/13/ross_ihaka_to_r/)

Comment: @geektrader no, at least that was not what I was thinking of, which was something one of the two original authors of R was doing as a research project. I don't think that language is as far along as Julia and I haven't heard anything since about the new language.

Comment: @geektrader I've now located what I was going on about and added links to the answer. Enjoy.

Comment: thanks very much for clearing that up! I thought this would be an issue when trying to make a numeric vector of several means, but it worked fine.